# Wordpress slider thumb, how to limit to first 6 with array?

Tags: arrays, wordpress, slider, limit, thumbnails

I'm trying to limit the thumbs shown by the following code to the first 6 items in the slider, only I can't get it to work. Does anyone know how to do what I'm looking for please?

```
<ul class="pictures-2">
<?php
foreach( $properties_images as $prop_image_id=>$prop_image_meta ){
$slider_thumb = wp_get_attachment_image_src($prop_image_id,'property-thumb-image');
echo '<li>';
echo '<img src="'.$slider_thumb[0].'" alt="'.$prop_image_meta['title'].'" />';
echo '</li>';
}
?>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<ul class="pictures-2">
    <?php
    $i=0;
    foreach( $properties_images as $prop_image_id=>$prop_image_meta ){
        $i++;
        if ($i <= 6) {
            $slider_thumb = wp_get_attachment_image_src($prop_image_id,'property-thumb-image');
            echo '<li>';
            echo '<img src="'.$slider_thumb[0].'" alt="'.$prop_image_meta['title'].'" />';
            echo '</li>';
        } else {
            //Do Nothing
        }
    }
?>
</ul>
```

Comment: This is allowing to go through the loop 6 times, otherwise nothing happens.

Comment: @sshare, glad I could help!